# Screen Resolution Stuck @ 640 x 480

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 17.10, display-resolution

Dummy here

On Thursday night I ventured into synaptic and noticed some recommended packages to download... so I foolishly downloaded them... the next day I booted up and my screen resolution is frozen is stuck at 640-488. I cannot see which package messed up my resolution.

I would be very grateful for any helpful suggestions. I looked around for solutions and saw one suggesting deleting or editing the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file, but I am unable to find it.

```
System:    Host: zoe-ZBOX-EN1070-1060 Kernel: 4.13.0-36-generic x86_64
           bits: 64 gcc: 7.2.0
           Desktop: MATE 1.18.0 (Gtk 3.22.25)
           Distro: Ubuntu 17.10
Machine:   Device: desktop Mobo: Motherboard by ZOTAC model: ZBOX-EN1070/1060 v: Rev.00 serial: N/A
           UEFI [Legacy]: American Megatrends v: B333P009 date: 11/08/2016
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i5-6400T (-MCP-) 
           arch: N/A cache: 6144 KB

           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 17664
           clock speeds: max: 2800 MHz 1: 2200 MHz
           2: 2200 MHz 3: 2200 MHz 4: 2200 MHz
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GP104M [GeForce GTX 1070 Mobile]
           bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.5 )
           drivers: fbdev (unloaded: modesetting,vesa) FAILED: nouveau
           Resolution: 640x480@73.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 5.0, 256 bits)
           version: 3.3 Mesa 17.2.8 Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 NVIDIA GP104 High Def. Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 01:00.1
           Card-2 Intel Sunrise Point-H HD Audio
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1f.3
           Sound: ALSA v: k4.13.0-36-generic
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCIE Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: d000
           bus-ID: 02:00.0
           IF: enp2s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full
           mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCIE Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: c000
           bus-ID: 03:00.0
           IF: enp3s0 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-3: Intel Wireless 3165
           driver: iwlwifi bus-ID: 04:00.0
           IF: wlp4s0 state: down mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 500.1GB (26.2% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: Samsung_SSD_850 size: 250.1GB

           ID-2: /dev/sdb model: Samsung_SSD_850 size: 250.1GB

Partition: ID-1: / size: 37G used: 23G (66%)
           fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
           ID-2: /home size: 176G used: 84G (51%)
           fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda3
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 17.52GB used: 0.00GB (0%)
           fs: swap dev: /dev/sda4
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 59.0C mobo: 29.8C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 259 Uptime: 0 min Memory: 1081.3/15997.5MB
           Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 7.2.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.4.121) inxi: 2.3.37
```

---

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for zoe: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP104M [GeForce GTX 1070 Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

---

```
$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   640x480       73.00*
```

Comment: it is difficult to read unformatted text. can you please use `code` formatting  ?

Answer (score 1):

YAY fixed... I remembered. Copying and pasting my synaptic downloads I spotted Bumblebee, which I half-remembered another post on frozen resolutions mentioning.

I removed Bumblebee - problem solved.